# Routes Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, route, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde galera, percebi que o Laravel 5.3 possui uma nova pasta "Route", com as rotas. Por padrão ele utiliza a web.php

Gostaria de saber, como posso fazer para criar outras rotas sem ser dentro do web.php, gostaria de separar assim.

web.php darshboard.php usuario.php ...etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Na lhe impede de criar o seu proprio padrão, todavia o ideal é organizar nos Controllers e Views isso, e no web.php você pode usar `Route::group`, por exemplo:

```
/*
 * todas rotas acessam a partir do namespace "App\Http\Controllers\Homepage"
 * todas rotas acessam a partir do path "/"
 */
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Homepage'], function() {
    /*
     * Isto será acessível via http://localhost/
     * O arquivo da classe será: app/Http/Controllers/Homepage/Main.php
     */
    Route::get('/', 'Main@index');

    /*
     * Isto será acessível via http://localhost/about
     * O arquivo da classe será: app/Http/Controllers/Homepage/Main.php
     */
    Route::get('/about', 'Main@about');
});

/*
 * todas rotas acessam a partir do namespace "App\Http\Controllers\Admin"
 * todas rotas acessam a partir do path "/admin/"
 */
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    /*
     * Isto será acessível via http://localhost/admin/
     * O arquivo da classe será: app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Main.php
     */
    Route::get('/', 'Main@index');

    /*
     * Isto será acessível via http://localhost/admin/user
     * O arquivo da classe será: app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Main.php
     */
    Route::get('/user', 'Main@user');
});

/*
 * todas rotas acessam a partir do namespace "App\Http\Controllers\Api"
 * todas rotas acessam a partir do path "/api/"
 */
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    /*
     * Isto será acessível via:
     * - http://localhost/api/photos
     * - http://localhost/api/photos/create
     * - http://localhost/api/photo/{id}/edit
     *
     * O arquivo da classe será: app/Http/Controllers/Api/PhotoController.php
     */
    Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
});
```

Desta maneira o web.php não ficará grande, as rotas permanecem em apenas um lugar e tudo ficará organizado dentro dos controllers.

Note que `Closures` não suportam o cache de rotas, já os controllers sim, o que pode ser uma vantagem.

Claro que nada lhe impede de criar 3 arquivos separados e usar `require_once`:

- routes/homepage.php

  ```
  <?php

  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Homepage'], function() {
      Route::get('/', 'Main@index');
      Route::get('/about', 'Main@about');
  });
  ```
- routes/admin.php

  ```
  <?php

  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
      Route::get('/', 'Main@index');
      Route::get('/about', 'Main@user');
  });
  ```
- routes/api.php

  ```
  <?php

  Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'prefix' => 'api'], function() {
       Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
  });
  ```
- E no routes/web.php:

  ```
  <?php

  require_once base_path('routes/homepage.php');
  require_once base_path('routes/admin.php');
  require_once base_path('routes/api.php');
  ```

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Amigo, para utlizar vários arquivos, existem algumas opções, uma delas é editar este service provider `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`, onde exstem os seguinte métodos:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });

    //Este aqui eu adicionei como exemplo, não está no core
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], //quantos middlewares forem necessários, apenas lembre de adiciona-los no kernel.php
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, //'App\Http\Controllers'
        'prefix' => 'user'
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/usuario.php');
    });
}

protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
```

Neste caso você adicionaria novos grupos de rotas para cada um de seus arquivos.

É possível também incluir estes novos grupos dretamente no próprio `web.php`.

Comment: É, realmente é melhor incluir novos grupos diretamente na `web.php`.  As outras opções são para casos onde é necessário distinguir muito bem as coisas.  É claro que organização é algo pessoal, mas é bom seguir o padrão o framework. +1

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Faltou colocar que quando se define o "middleware" eh necessario acrescentalo no kernel.php.

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe, eu coloquei somente para mostrar que era possível...hehe #editado